# what does hosts per network and number of network mean?

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip, hosts

My question is basic, but I do not understand what exactly is meant by `hosts per network` and `Number of Network`

[This link](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPAddressClassABandCNetworkandHostCapacities.htm) classifies IP Address as `Class A,B,C`. and in each one there is column for `host IDs per network` and `number of possible networks`. but I am having difficulty understanding what these mean exactly? can some one give a simple example to illustrate?
may be some example that involves day-to-day services. (`google`,`microsoft`? ect).

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (before the Internet even went commercial) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing). Network classes have not been used this century.

Answer (score 2):

The first four bits of an IP address determine the class of the network. The class specifies how many of the remaining bits belong to the prefix (aka Network ID) and to the suffix (aka Host ID). The first three classes, A, B and C, are the primary network classes.

When interacting with mere humans, software uses dotted decimal notation; each 8 bits is treated as an unsigned binary integer separated by periods. IP reserves host address 0 to denote a network. 140.211.0.0 denotes the network that was assigned the class B prefix 140.211.

[From :](http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/protocols/protocols-ip/165-protocols-ip-network-id.html)

> The network Class helps us determine how the 4 byte, or 32 Bit, IP
>   Address is divided between network and node portions. Think of the
>   Network ID as the suburb you live in and the Node ID your street in
>   that suburb. You can tell exactly where someone is if you have their
>   suburb and street name. In the same way, the Network ID tells us which
>   network a particular computer belongs to and the Node ID identifies
>   that computer from all the rest that reside in the same network.

The table below shows you (in binary) how the Network ID and Node ID changes depending on the Class:
[image: Img]

The picture below gives you a small example to help you understand the concept:
[image: Img]

> Explanation:
>
> In the above picture, you can see a small network. We have assigned a
>   Class C IP Range for this network. Remember that Class C IP Addresses
>   are for small networks. Looking now at Host A, you will see that its
>   IP Address is 192.168.0.2. The Network ID portion of this IP Address
>   is in blue, while the Host ID is in orange.

Another Example for the same concept is clearly explained in [image: pic]

Comment: great stuff! Excellent visuals

Comment: "_The first four bits of an IP address determine the class of the network._" No, network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (before the Internet even went commercial) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing). Network classes have not been used this century.

Answer (score 0):

Each IPV4 address is 32 bits and divided into 2 parts: bits for host and bytes for network.

For Class A :8 bits from 32 are for network identification and 
             24 bits from 32 are for host identification and
             As there are 8 bits for network we can have 2 power 8 = 256 networks (number of network). 
             Each network among 256 can have 2 power 24 host (that host per network).

Hope this explains for Class A

Comment: Host is the computer/Device connected to the network. And network is a logical entity connecting computer/devices.

Comment: "_Each IPV4 address is 32 bytes..._" No, each IPv4 address is 32 _bits_. Also, network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (before the Internet even went commercial) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Network classes have not been used this century.

Answer (score -1):

class A have a 1 network and 3 host .So you can multiply 2 the power 24 you will get the answer

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (before the Internet even went commercial) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing). Network classes have not been used this century.